# What is my relationship to a cousin who's 5th Great Grandparents are my 12th Great Grandparents?

Tags: kinship-terminology

This person I am referring to is Martha Wayles who was born in 1748 and died in 1782. I've been trying to wrap my brain around the x cousin x times removed thing but it is still confusing me. [image: The Red circle is me The pink is the ancestor in question. I would also like to know who I'm related to the one in blue.]

The red circle is me. The pink circle is the cousin in question. And the blue one is one I'd like to know how we are connected as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you'd be 6th cousins, 7 times removed to Martha Wayles.